# panic: cannot find Asia/Tokyo" in zip file /usr/local/go/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip

Tags: go, docker

Docker上でgolangのプログラムを動かしたいのですが、`gorm`というデータベース用のライブラリでタイトルのようなエラーが出ました。

エラーが出た箇所は`gorm`の初期化時で

```
db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Asia%2FTokyo")
```

の箇所です。コンテナをコミットして中に入り、実際にZIPファイルを展開して中を見ましたが`Asia/Tokyo`は存在していたので、なぜ、見つけられないのか疑問です。どなたかわかる方いらっしゃらないでしょうか。

使用したDockerfileはgolang:alpineです。

以下は作成したDockerfileです。

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine

ADD . /go/src/github.com/username/appname
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/username/appname
RUN apk add --update git

RUN go get -u github.com/Masterminds/glide
RUN glide install
RUN go install

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: また`Asia/Tokyo`の部分を`Local`に変更しても同様のエラーがでました。

Comment: 今になって気が付いたのですが、エラーメッセージが `cannot find Asia/Tokyo" in zip file ...` となっていて `Asia/Tokyo` の末尾部分に `"` が付いています。これは書き間違いでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り`"`が原因のようでした。Dockerに環境変数をファイルで渡しましたが、そのときに`""`で囲ってしまっていたのが原因でした。ありがとうございます。